# Upload an image to an Android Studio Recyclerview, from a directory path

Tags: retrofit2

First of all I appreciate your attention and the help you can give me. I have a problem with loading an image being hosted in a server directory. I am generating the view from recyclerview, I am using Retrofit library.
The response generated by the WS is the following after a query for the ID:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "hello",
        "detail": "sss",
        "path_image": "images/hello.jpg"
    }
]
```

The other fields return me successfully with the following code from the RecyclerAdpater in Android studio:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewholder holder, final int position) 
{
 holder.txtId.setText(myimages.get(position).getId());
 holder.txtMsj.setText(myimages.get(position).getName());
 holder.txtDE.setText(myimages.get(position).getDetail()); 
}
```

I will also place the table of the BD to which I am addressing the data mentioning also that I have generated my get & set in AS of these fields:

```
create TABLE images2 (
 id int NOT NULL identity primary key,
 name varchar(100) NULL,
 detail varchar(100) NULL,
 image varchar(max),
 path_image varchar(50) NULL
)
```

As I mentioned earlier, the image is being stored in a directory with the name and extension of said image inserted from the same application, however after several unsuccessful investigations of the case, I still have the problem of visualizing said image. I would be very grateful if there is any tool or line of code that would help me complete the objective. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the Glide library.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewholder holder, final int position) 
{
 holder.txtId.setText(myimages.get(position).getId());
 holder.txtMsj.setText(myimages.get(position).getName());
 holder.txtDE.setText(myimages.get(position).getDetail()); 

 Glide.with(context).load("MY_URL_IMAGES/"+myimages.get(position).getPath_image()).into(holder.ivPec);

}
```